# Precision of numbers, multiply and divide by 100

Tags: c, currency

I have the following test cases

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 

    double x = 3.987;

    printf("x = %lf\n", x);

    printf("(double) (long) (x) = %lf\n", (double) (long) (x));

    printf("(x*100)/100 = %lf\n", (x*100)/100);

    printf("(double) (long) (x*100)/100 = %lf\n", (double) (long) (x*100)/100);

    printf("(double) (long) (x*10)/10 = %lf\n", (double) (long) (x*10)/10);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
x = 3.987000
(double) (long) (x) = 3.000000
(x*100)/100 = 3.987000
(double) (long) (x*100)/100 = 3.980000
(double) (long) (x*10)/10 = 3.900000
```

It seems to me that multiplying by 100 and dividing by 100 would cancel each other out? but It is actually decreasing the precision. How does this work exactly?

Comment: Even if you actually did multiply by 100 and then immediately divided by 100, for a lot of numbers it wouldn't "cancel out" - floating point numbers aren't algebra, they're limited in precision and range, and moreover use base 2 so reasoning about them in base 10 fails.

Comment: Remove `(long)`, that is making conversion to integers, and you lose precision because of that.

Comment: Why are you casting to `long`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type casting to `long` has higher precedence than deviding by 100. So

```
(double) (long) (x*100)/100
```

actually is equivalent to

```
((double) (long) (x*100)) / 100
```

not to

```
(double) (long) ((x*100)/100)
```

Answer (score 5):

In some places you're casting to "long", and it's **an integer type**. So for example in the last case, you're multiplying 3.987 by 10 and you get 39.87. Then, you're casting it to "long" so it becomes 39. After dividing it by 10 you get 3.9.

What do you want to achieve by using `(long)`?